# Retrieve data from android application

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm making an application for my portfolio - a simple android game with no specific genre or gameplay, just a mixture of some fancy ideas implementations. Currently I am stuck with a question how to implement one of the features because it requires interaction with other aplications.

Let's say I have a butterfly with procedural textures on its wings. I already implemented the gameObject of a butterfly itself and two layers of textures - static background and procedural colored lines on it. The procedural layer receives a function, makes a fractal image based on it, paints it and updates the texture. Currently it utilizes a simple sin(x) function, but what I want it to is to use a function that is stored in another application.

The function source application connects to a remote server, receives a buffer with f(x) values and displays it for its own purpose. What I was trying to google (i'm kinda new to android) is how can I either

- Run the function source application in something like "windowed mode", cut the "window" to the function itself and put it on the layer without using fractals
- Hook into function source application memory and retrieve the buffer
- Capture the packets going to the application

...but failed. Application itself is made not by myself, so I neither can make it declare the variables public static, nor pass the variables or pointers when I need it. And, obviously, I can't code the function itself - I just don't know the function itself.

I am looking for suggestions and any help to implement this feature.
P.S. Game engine - Unity 3D, scripting language - C#
P.S.S. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

if the source of your function (please try to *name* stuff for easier understanding), that I will call function F for fractal, is an Android application FractakApp, it is mandatory that this FractalApp makes the result available. If the developper of FractalApp has not prepared something to share the function F result, you are screwed. Indeed, Android OS is based on sandbox and no application can access other application data if no output was built in.

That said, StackOverflow.com is not made for open end question and general discussion but for precise issue.

I guess you are an experiment developer, right ?